# Данное подключение фавиконки будет работать на всех устройствах и браузерах?

Tags: html, css

вот так, без манифеста

```html
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" type="image/ico" href="/favicon//apple-touch-icon.ico" sizes="180x180">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="/favicon/favicon-16.ico" sizes="16x16">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="/favicon/favicon-24.ico" sizes="24x24">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="/favicon/favicon-32.ico" sizes="32x32">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="/favicon/favicon-64.ico" sizes="64x64">
```

Comment: Надо тестить ...

Comment: В винде, в панели, используется 240*180 вроде